# Changing the File Creation Date in C++ using windows.h in Windows 7

Tags: c++, file, datetime, file-properties

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    onelog a;
    std::cout << "a new project";

    //creates a file as varuntest.txt
    ofstream file("C:\\users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\varuntest.txt", ios::app);

    SYSTEMTIME thesystemtime;
    GetSystemTime(&thesystemtime);

    thesystemtime.wDay = 07;//changes the day
    thesystemtime.wMonth = 04;//changes the month
    thesystemtime.wYear = 2012;//changes the year

    //creation of a filetimestruct and convert our new systemtime
    FILETIME thefiletime;

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&thesystemtime,&thefiletime);

    //getthe handle to the file
    HANDLE filename = CreateFile("C:\\users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\varuntest.txt", 
                                FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //set the filetime on the file
    SetFileTime(filename,(LPFILETIME) NULL,(LPFILETIME) NULL,&thefiletime);

    //close our handle.
    CloseHandle(filename);


    return 0;
}
```

Now the question is; it only changes the modified date when I check the properties of the file. I need to ask;

> How to change the file's creation date instead of the modification
>   date?

Thanks

Please give some code for this novice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sets the last modified time because that's what you asked it to do. The function receives 3 filetime parameters and you only passed a value to the final one, `lpLastWriteTime`. To set the creation time call the function like this:

```
SetFileTime(filename, &thefiletime, (LPFILETIME) NULL,(LPFILETIME) NULL);
```

I suggest you take a read of the documentation for [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The key part is its signature which is as follows:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetFileTime(
  __in      HANDLE hFile,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpCreationTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastAccessTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastWriteTime
);
```

Since you say that you are a novice with the Windows API I'll give you a tip. The documentation on MSDN is very comprehensive. Whenever you get stuck with a Win32 API call, look it up on MSDN.

And some comments on your code:

- You should always check the return values for any API calls. If you call the functions incorrectly, or they fail for some other reason, you'll find it impossible to work out what went wrong without error checking.
- The variable that you call `filename` should in fact be named `fileHandle`.

Comment: thesystemtime.wDay = 07;//changes the day
thesystemtime.wMonth = 04;//changes the month
thesystemtime.wYear = 2012;//changes the year
can u suggest something to pass the current system date

Comment: @gandhigcpp Before I answer another different question, could I ask you to review your existing questions (including this one) and accept the most helpful answer, where possible, as per the [faq].

Comment: :i accepted it but ca u also reply to the one i asked in the comments

Comment: And what about all your other questions?

Comment: :i will surely do that ,actually i got to complete something once u reply to this and once i m finished off with somethig i would surely do that it is a promis e u can cross check tomorrow

Comment: [`GetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390.aspx) obtains the current system time. But you are already using that. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: :i m working on something that requires me to change the creation date of the file so i thought if i could pass the system day,month,year here it would be changed as he system time chnageg...

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. What is your input data?

Comment: :i m on a logging project can u share some personal input ike emailaddress with me if u dont mind

Comment: No, that's not what we do here.

Comment: :then i would tell u here what i need ow is some thing that instead of assigning thesystemtime.wDay = 07;//07 as as hard quoted gives here the system day ,similary for month,year

Comment: `GetSystemTime` does just that. After calling `GetSystemTime(&thesystemtime);`, `thesystemtime` contains the current time and date.

Comment: so i just need to write thesystemtime.wDay;similarly for all the ither things

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. If you want more help from me you will need to write down clearly and precisely what you want. I just don't understand these snippets.