# How to modify a text file's "Date modified" property without affecting the content using c++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I was doing a unit testing on one of my method. One criteria for the method to select the file into the result vector is the file is updated from last few hours.
However, to ensure there is a valid result whenever I run the test, I need to keep at least one of the file "up to date".

**Any idea about how to approach this except trying to copy the file to a temp file and write it back to the original file**?

Edit:
I am using VS2013 C++ and my OS is windows 7.

Comment: An old developer MS-DOS tool was "Touch". It was a command line tool that allowed a user to set the modified date to whatever they wanted on a single file or everything in a directory tree.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: @mustafa-chelik I have edited my post. Many thanks for throwing this out

Comment: @StarPilot  there a way I can do through only programming but not calling any extra tool? Many thanks for your answer too.

Comment: ok, so you want to change a file's modified date to current time? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: By the way you could mock that date since basically you don't want to test if windows did his job of giving you the date. Testing with actual files are considered functional (or system, etc) test.

Comment: If you are willing to write code, it is trivial to use the common disk IO functions to locate your file, and update its date modified. See the question I linked in my answer as that is also discussed there in the accepted answer.

Comment: @mustafa-chelik yes, that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041651/changing-the-file-creation-date-in-c-using-windows-h-in-windows-7

Have you tried opening and closing the file?

Comment: Fredrik Mörk's answer lists using the .Net functions to do what you ask.

Comment: @laurent-jalbert-simard that is a very good point, I should be able to mock the last_Modify time instead of changing it every single time.

Comment: Will `SetFileTime` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) be sufficient?

Comment: @iheanyi  @ caramiriell    I will give it a try in a minute. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From code

If you need to set if from your code itself, see Fredrik Mörk's answer (the accepted answer) on SuperUser site:

[Using copy command to just change the time and date of a file on Windows OS](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch)

Text copy of Fredrik Mörk's answer :

If you feel like coding it yourself, .NET offers the `File.SetLastAccessTime`, `File.SetCreationTime` and `File.SetLastWriteTime` methods.

### From external tool

If you need to set it from an outside tool, such as cmd.exe, See Gish Domains' answer on SuperUser site:

[Using copy command to just change the time and date of a file on Windows OS](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch)

Text copy of link:

If you want to touch the date stamp of a file using windows, use the following command at the command prompt:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

(where filename.ext is your file's name). The +,, is a special flag to copy telling it to simply update the date/time on the file:

- Changing the time and date of a file

If you want to assign the current time and date to a file without modifying the file, use the following syntax:

```
copy /b Source+,,
```

The commas indicate the omission of the Destination parameter.

Edit based on comments by Lumi and Justin: put this in a batch file, eg. touch.cmd

```
@COPY /B %1+,, %1
```

This works even if the file is not in the current directory (tested on Windows 7).

Comment: Oh indeed there are methods to do it.. thanks. Can you revise your answer a little bit to include Fredrik Mörk's answer? And please keep the content of your answer too because i think it's useful for people to know

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has c++ tag and you are using Windows, you can open the file and change it's last modified property using this code:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("c:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if(hFile != INVALID_FILE_HANDLE)
{
    FILETIME filetime;
    SYSTEMTIME systemfile;

    GetSystemTime(&systemfile);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&systemfile, &filetime);
    SetFileTime(hFile, NULL, NULL, &filetime);
    CloseFile(hFile);
}
```

Comment: many thanks for sharing this. Although I have accepted the other answer few minutes before your post. I think the codes here is more relevant to the question.

Comment: @StarPilot but your answer also includes the info needed for the question.

Comment: Where is INVALID_FILE_HANDLE and CloseFile() defined?

Comment: @SteveSmith just include windows.h

Comment: The proper way would be to check INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE instead. According to the documentation that's what CreateFile returns if it fails.

Comment: The documentation of CreateFile also says use CloseHandle to close the file.

Answer (score -3):

To update the modified date and time to the current time, on just about any platform:

```
// #include <stdio.h>
FILE* pFile = fopen("filepath.txt", "ab");
if (pFile)
  fclose(pFile);
```

Or, as a one-liner using STL:

```
// #include <fstream>
std::fstream("filepath.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary).close();
```

Comment: Neither of these methods seemed to have any effect on the file dates.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't change the file modified date...